# Elegant way of determining recipes I could cook with my ingredients

Tags: mysql, sql

I like to make cocktails on new year's eve and have quite a few recipes. This year, I want to make it smaller, minimizing the amount of opened juices etc, so I took the time to dump all of the recipes I like into a MySQL database, basically having the following format:

```
RECIPE
    RID (INT, PK, auto_inc)
    NAME (VARCHAR)

INGREDIENT
    IID (INT, PK, auto_inc)
    NAME (VARCHAR)

RECIPE_INGREDIENT
    RID (INT, FK to RECIPE.RID)
    IID (INT, FK to INGREDIENT.IID)
    AMOUNT (VARCHAR)
    PK: RID, IID
```

What I want to do now is to say "I cannot do without cocktail x, y and z". Determining the ingredients needed to make x, y and z is trivial.

But what would be an elegant way of answering the question "If I have the ingredients i<sub>1</sub>, i<sub>2</sub> and i<sub>3</sub>, what recipes can I make?"

What comes to my mind quickly is a procedure that iterates over *all* recipes and adds them to the set that is returned at the end only if there is no rid_iid mapping for it whose iid is not in the given set of iids. But I am not a database or sql guru and quite tired right now, so I think there could be something more ingeniuos...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select ri.rid
from recipe_ingredient ri
group by ri.rid
having sum( ri.iid not in (@i1, @i2, @i3 )) = 0;
```

Comment: I think if you add _join_ to your code it would be more useful.

Comment: @mustafa.akcoban . . . Not if the `join` is not needed.

Comment: Now, *that's* elegant! And I've learned that you can put fancy stuff inside the `SUM(...)`! Thanks a lot. :-)